# Problemas con java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, mysql, login, tomcat, nullpointerexception

Tengo un problema con el Login, aplicando la misma metodologia que desarrolle con otra aplicacion web me sale el sgte error:

```
Descripción El servidor encontró un error interno que hizo que no pudiera rellenar este requerimiento.

excepción

java.lang.NullPointerException
    Controlador.UsuarioController.processRequest(UsuarioController.java:58)
    Controlador.UsuarioController.doPost(UsuarioController.java:146)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

DTO Usuario (todas tienen sus getters and setters)

```
 public class Usuario {
    int idUsu;
    String nombre;
    String apellido;
    String correo;
    String contraseña;
    int telefono;
    String tipoUsu;
    Date fechaRegistro;

public Usuario(){
    
}

public Usuario(int idUsu, String nombre, String apellido, String correo, String contraseña, int telefono, String tipoUsu, Date fechaRegistro) {
    this.idUsu = idUsu;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
    this.correo = correo;
    this.contraseña = contraseña;
    this.telefono = telefono;
    this.tipoUsu = tipoUsu;
    this.fechaRegistro = fechaRegistro;
}

public Usuario(String correo,String contraseña){
   this.correo = correo;
   this.contraseña =contraseña;
}
```

DAO UsuarioDAO

```
public class UsuarioDAO implements IOperacionesBD<Usuario>{

private static PreparedStatement pstm = null;
private static ResultSet res = null;
private static final String SQL_INSERT = "insert into usuario values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
private static final String SQL_LOGIN="select * from usuario where correo=? and contraseña=?";    

Conexion con = Conexion.generarInstancia();
    public Usuario login(Usuario usuario){
Usuario usuarioAux=null;
try {
    pstm = con.getCon().prepareStatement(SQL_LOGIN);
    pstm.setString(1,usuario.getCorreo());
    pstm.setString(2,usuario.getContraseña());
    res = pstm.executeQuery();
    while(res.next()){
    usuarioAux = new Usuario(res.getString(2),res.getString(3),res.getString(4),res.getString(5),res.getInt(6),res.getString(7));
    }

} catch (Exception e) {

    System.out.println("Error en el login :"+e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
cerrarConexion();
}
return
```

Controlador UsuarioController

```
   protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    String accion = request.getParameter("accion");
    
    if (accion.equals("login")) {
        String correo = request.getParameter("txtCorreo");
        String contraseña = request.getParameter("txtContraseña");
        
        Usuario usuario = new Usuario(correo, contraseña);
        UsuarioDAO usuarioDAO = new UsuarioDAO();
        usuario = usuarioDAO.login(usuario);
        if(correo.trim().isEmpty() && contraseña.trim().isEmpty()){
        String error="Complete todos los campos";
        request.getSession().setAttribute("lerror", error);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("lerror.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } else if(correo.trim().isEmpty() && contraseña.length()>0){
        String error="Complete el campo correo";
        request.getSession().setAttribute("error", error);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("lerror.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
```

// la linea de abajo es la linea 58

```
        else if(correo.length()>0 && contraseña.trim().isEmpty()){
        String error="Complete el campo contraseña";
        request.getSession().setAttribute("error", error);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("lerror.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
        else if (usuario!=null){
        HttpSession objsession = request.getSession(true);
        objsession.setAttribute("usuario", usuario);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("calculadora.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }else{
        String error="No se encuentra registrado en nuestro sistema. Registrarse para iniciar sesion";
        request.getSession().setAttribute("error", error);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("error.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

y aca el JSP Login

```
                            <div class="card-body">
                            <form action="UsuarioController?accion=login" method="post" name="formLogin">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="txtCorreo">Correo:</label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="txtCorreo" id="txtCorreo"  placeholder="Ingresar Correo">
                                    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted"></small>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="txtContraseña">Contraseña:</label>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="txtContraseña" id="txtContraseña" placeholder="Ingresar Contraseña">
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light" style="background-color: #C5CAE9;">Iniciar Sesión</button>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <a href="#" style="color:#3F51B5;">Recuperar contraseña</a>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
```

En otra Aplicación Web que cree si me sirvio no entiendo porque ahora no, lei algo sobre el null pero no puedo identificar mi error, mi base de datos solo esta conformada por una tabla Usuario (id,nombre,apellido,correo,contraseña,telefono,tipousuario,fecharegistro), trabajo con Mysql, usando un test pude confirmar que si registra y logea:

```
public class testing {

//psvm
public static void main(String[] args) {

    
    
    Conexion.generarInstancia();
    Usuario usuario = new Usuario("Paolo", "Guerrero", "paguerrero@gmail.com", "123", 987654124, "admin");
    UsuarioDAO usuarioDAO = new UsuarioDAO();

    if (usuarioDAO.insert(usuario)) {
        System.out.println("Se inserto correctamente");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No se insertaron los datos");
    }

    String correo="rogeraxelpro@gmail.com" ;
    String contraseña="987654321";
    Usuario usuarioLogin = new Usuario(correo, contraseña);
    UsuarioDAO usuarioDAO1 = new UsuarioDAO();
    usuarioLogin = usuarioDAO1.login(usuarioLogin);

      if (usuarioLogin!=null) {
          System.out.println("Bienvenido al sistema"+usuarioLogin);
      } else {

          System.out.println("No se encuentra usuario en la bd");

      }
```

me sale que si registra y logea, por ende mi conexion con la bd esta bien.

Comment: ¿Podrías señalar la línea 58 de `UsuarioController` con un comentario? Algo como `//Aqui está el error`

Comment: ok, ya lo señale

Comment: cuando borro las validaciones de completar campos, se salta la primera condicion y pasa a la sgte condicion donde si carga Error.jsp

Comment: Hay una cosa que no estás considerando en tu código, y es que la primera validación que debes hacer es preguntar si `correo` y `contraseña` es distinto de `null`. No es lo mismo preguntar si está vacío a si es null. Esa es la primera de todas las validaciones y de las más importantes que no estoy viendo, porque esa es la que evita que te lance el NPE. Por otro lado, por favor, agrega un `System.out.print()` debajo de correo y contraseña donde los imprimas y cheques que te están llegando esos datos del front.

Comment: Concuerdo con @JaimeMenéndez, sería primeramente validar que los parámetros de correo y contraseña no sean nulos, y a mi punto de vista, pudiera causar ruido el parámetro de contraseña, posiblemente la letra ñ no se esté codificando correctamente, intenta omitir la ñ en el nombre del parámetro de contraseña y realiza la prueba nuevamente y nos comentas.

Comment: cambie contraseña por contrasena en todo, y ya no me bota ese error, aunque creo que algo sigue mal, igual muchas gracias, era mi primera vez en esta plataforma, y recibí ayuda inmediata.

Comment: @Axel añade la solucion en una respuesta para futuros usuarios :)